# Multiple pages in one HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I've been experimenting with Cordova/Phonegap for iOS, and it has a `www` directory that is read when the application launches. This directory is readonly meaning I can't add any of my own files into it (it won't let me either.) Does this mean that I should have multiple "pages" of my app from only one index.html file? How would I go about doing this?

**UPDATE** 
If you are using Cordova/Phonegap, just create a separate file in a text editor, save as HTML, and drag it into the `/www` folder before opening up Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hell no!,

I have no idea why your index is read-only, but just turn it off, you are not forced to use multiple pages in the same html, but if you really want to, you can just use `jQuery-mobile`, then each `<div data-role="page">` will be one different page

Comment: Thanks! The problem was actually pretty silly once I figured it out, but I will still look at jQuery-mobile.

Comment: no problem, if you will be using high ammount of content/pages, it's preffered to use separated htmls, or even load dynamicaly than all pages on same file

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries to accomplish that, like for example JQuery Mobile, or basic javascript scripts.

Here you have an example with Jquery Mobile: [Demo of Pages with JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/widgets/pages/)